# Azure WebApp scaling through powershell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

**Scenario:** 
I host my application in 2 Azure regions and expecting only one region to take traffic at any point of time. I can control that through traffic manager through fail over mode. Now, I want to manage (enable/ disable) scaling automatically based on which region is taking traffic (through Azure automation). I wrote PS to the point where i can identify which region is taking traffic using traffic manager cmdlets

**Ask:** 
Can this be achieved through Power shell?

Comment: Are you looking to set up auto-scale via PowerShell, or simply to set the number of workers to some fixed value that your script chooses?

Comment: This is not what you're looking for? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/28/use-powershell-to-scale-azure-websites/

Comment: @OlaEkdahl Your link doesn't contain any PowerShell; it contains instructions for adding automation to call a PowerShell script. That article then links to _another_ page, which details the script in question. It's best to post a proper answer, with the proper PowerShell script shown, maybe an example, and a link to the documented PowerShell script page (not the runbook page). Also note: The PowerShell script in question is not part of the Azure Powershell distro - it's a separate sample. That said - it might be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I agree that it's not a great and by any means a complete answer. That's why I posted it as a comment :)

Comment: @OlaEkdahl I know. I'm saying... it has the makings of a great answer. :)

Comment: @David Ebbo Auto-Scale would be the best option for my ask

Comment: @OlaEkdahl Thanks, I read the article too and for me it is a high level design on how it can be done using cmdlets and webhook.  I looking for help to achieve this through a complete PS script